# Code won't process second upload correctly in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

First time it works correctly but the second time same file upload it shows this error:

```
The process cannot access the file 'D:....\UploadedFiles\FileName.xls' because it is being used by another process.
```

Here is my code:

```
 public ActionResult ImportExcel1()
 {
    try
    {
        string path1 = string.Format("{0}/{1}", Server.MapPath("~/UploadedFiles"), Request.Files["FileUpload1"].FileName);
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(path1)) {
            System.IO.File.Delete(path1);
        }
        Request.Files["FileUpload1"].SaveAs(path1);

        Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
        Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(path1);
        Excel.Worksheet xlSheet = xlWorkbook.Sheets[1]; // get first sheet
        Excel.Range xlRange = xlSheet.UsedRange; // get the entire used range


        int numberOfRows = xlRange.Rows.Count;
        int numberOfCols = xlRange.Columns.Count;

        string slNo = "";
        string batchCode = "";
        string name = "";
        string districtName = "";
        string rollNo = "";
        List<int> columnsToRead = new List<int>();

        for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfCols; i++)
        {
            //if (xlRange.Cells[1, i].Value2 != null) // ADDED IN EDIT
            //{

                columnsToRead.Add(i);
            //}
        }

        for (int j = 1; j <= numberOfRows; j++)
        {

            //if (xlRange.Cells[1, j].Value2 != null) // ADDED IN EDIT
            //{
            //if (xlRange.Cells[1, i].Value2.ToString().Equals("Currency Code"))
            //{
            //    columnsToRead.Add(i);
            //}
            List<int> rowsToRead = new List<int>();
            rowsToRead.Add(j);
            foreach (int c in columnsToRead)
            {
                // start at 2 because the first row is 1 and the header row
                foreach (int r in rowsToRead)
                {
                    //if (xlRange.Cells[r, c].Value2 != null) // ADDED IN EDIT
                    //{
                    List<string> columnValue = new List<string>();
                    if (xlRange.Cells[r, c].Value2 == null) // ADDED IN EDIT
                    {
                        string x = "";
                        x = (xlRange.Cells[r, c].Value2) = "";
                        columnValue.Add(x);
                    }
                    else {
                        columnValue.Add(xlRange.Cells[r, c].Value2.ToString());
                    }

                    if (c.ToString() == "1") {
                        slNo = columnValue[0].ToString();
                    }
                    if (c.ToString() == "2") {
                        batchCode = columnValue[0].PadLeft(4, '0').ToString();
                    }
                    if (c.ToString() == "3") {
                        name = columnValue[0].ToString();
                    }
                    if (c.ToString() == "4") {
                        districtName = columnValue[0].ToString();
                    }
                    if (c.ToString() == "5") {
                        rollNo = columnValue[0].ToString();
                    }
                }
                if (j > numberOfRows) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            SaveData(slNo, batchCode, name, districtName, rollNo);
        }

        xlApp.Workbooks.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Import");
}
```

Comment: thanks for eidt @Dawid

Comment: You're welcome, but do it yourself next time, please. Also it's important to mark your question with proper language tag.

Comment: Also did you hear about the [switch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t.aspx) already?

Comment: Looks like the file is not closed properly or two threads are trying to access same file.

Comment: Ok I'll try it...Hmm I hear about switch and I can apply it @ Dawid Ferenczy

Comment: How can I solve it....? Would you have any solution? In which line it occurs and how? please help @Sudipta Maiti

Comment: It's worth noting...don't do Excel automation on a web server. Ever. You will regret it. Use Aspose. Or an open xml library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.xls file is not closed properly.

```
xlWorkbook.Close(true, Type.Missing, Type.Missing); //Close() should have
//parameters based on your requirements.
xlApp.Workbooks.Close();
```

Also use finally block for proper clean up.